# unable to extract substring from gmail body using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am novice to google app script. can you please help to extract string from the below text ?

**Advertiser    Campaign**
Walgreens   FY20 RAD Conversion

I want to extract campaign name that is "FY20 RAD Conversion". Below I have used the code to extract but I have failed as if i use split advertiser name walgreens may appear in mail body as well . But i want o extract this instance.  can some on help me? below is my code

```
  var cmpname = message[t][x].getPlainBody().split('Walgreens')[1].split("\n")[0];
```

my sample message is

**Dear MediaCom_Walgreens team,
Your report on the following campaign with Integral is ready for download:
Advertiser  Campaign
Walgreens   FY20 RAD Conversion Acq**

and my desired text to extract from message is **FY20 RAD Conversion Acq**

does some one can help??

Comment: Please share a sample message and a desired output.

Comment: sample message is Dear MediaCom_Walgreens team,

Your report on the following campaign with Integral is ready for download:

Advertiser Campaign
Walgreens FY20 RAD Conversion Acq. and my desired out put is i want to extract   string "FY20 RAD Conversion Acq"

Comment: Please post it into your question

Comment: yes I have done thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function xtractString(s) {
  var s=s||'Dear MediaCom_Walgreens team, Your report on the following campaign with Integral is ready for download: Advertiser Campaign Walgreens FY20 RAD Conversion Acq.'
  Logger.log(s.slice(-s.split("").reverse().join("").indexOf('Walgreens'.split("").reverse().join("")),-1));
  //[20-05-18 13:56:45:821 MDT]  FY20 RAD Conversion Acq
}
```